# Метааналіз чи мета-аналіз чи мета аналіз?

Tags: правопис, разом-дефіс-окремо

Стаття вікіпедії містить метааналіз та мета-аналіз в одному тексті. Схожа ситуація зі словниками й енциклопедіями. Чи є різниця? Чи можна зробити вибір між ними із загальних міркувань? Яка форма імовірніше залишиться в майбутньому?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[«Український правопис» 2015, § 25.4.а](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par25p4a):

> **Разом пишуться** усі складноскорочені слова й похідні від них: Нацбанк, Міносвіти, міськрада, облвиконком, профспілка, соцстрах; профспілковий, соцстрахівський. Сюди належать і всі складноскорочені з першими частинами: авіа-, авто-, агро-, біо-, вело-, водо-, газо-, геліо-, гео-, гідро-, екзо-, екстра-, електро-, зоо-, ізо-, квазі-, кіно-, космо-, лже-, макро-, **мета**-, метео-, мікро-, мілі-, моно-, мото-, нео-, палео-, псевдо-, радіо-, рентгено-, соціо-, стерео-, супер-, теле-, термо-, турбо-, фоно-, фото- й под.

[«Український правопис» 2019, § 35.4.2](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf#page=34):

> **Разом пишемо** слова з першими регулярно вживаними іншомовними компонентами на голосний та приголосний: абро-, авіа-, авто- (‘само’, ‘автоматичний’), агро-, аеро-, аква-, алко-, арт-, астро-, аудіо-, біо-, боди-, боді- (перед голосним), веб-, геліо-, гео-, гідро-, дендро-, екзо-, еко-, економ-, етно-, євро-, зоо-, ізо-, кібер-, **мета**-, метео-, моно-, мото-, нарко-, нео-, онко-, палео-, пан-, пара-, поп-, прес-, псевдо-, соціо-, теле-, фіто-, фолк- (фольк-), фоно- та ін.: аброморфéма, авіарéйс, автовідповідáч, агробíзнес, аеромéтод, акватéхніка, алкотéст, артрúнок, астрокорéкція, аудіоальбóм, біоцúкл, бодибíлдинг, бодіáрт, вебсторíнка, геліоцéнтр, геополíтика, гідропáрк, дендропáрк, екопродýкти, економклáс, етногýрт, єврозо́на, євроремóнт, зоосáд, кібермашúна, **метамóва**, метеостáнція, моновистáва, мотокрóс, наркобíзнес, неомодерні́ст, онколікáрня, панамерикáнський, параолімпíєць, попмýзика, попгýрт, пресконферéнція, псевдонаýка, псевдогромадя́нський, соціосфéра, телехрóніка, фітотерапíя, фолкгýрт, фолькмýзика, фонозáпис; так само слова з питомими компонентами іно- (іншо-, інако-), лже-: інові́рець, іншові́рець, інакодýмець, іншодýмець; лжепрорóк, лжесвíдок.
>
> Примітка. Якщо такі іншомовні компоненти приєднані до власного імені, то їх пишемо з дефісом: пан-Єврóпа, псéвдо-Фáуст.

[«Словник української мови» в 20 томах, стаття «**метаана́ліз**»](https://sum20ua.com/Entry/index?wordid=204725&page=1606):

> **МЕТААНА́ЛІЗ**, [родовий відмінок однини — метаана́ліз]у, ч[оловічий рід]. Об'єднання результатів декількох досліджень методами статистики для перевірки однієї або кількох взаємопов'язаних наукових гіпотез. *Дистрофікам та людям, які страждають ожирінням, передчасна смерть загрожує однаково. До такого висновку вчені дійшли, провівши **метааналіз** даних, отриманих за підсумками 51 дослідження* (із журн.).

Comment: Дякую, @Sasha, що подивилися за мене в правопис:) Мені було страшно. А воно досить прямолінійно виявилося.